# best way to push out test builds for testers

Tags: android, testing

I was wondering if there was a recommended way to push new versions of an Android application to private testers, almost like the Android Market where the user would need a password to download it. It would be much easier than e-mailing apks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say create a website that requires a password to get to the page with the download link.

If you want to notify the user that a new update is ready, I do this by putting an XML file with a version number, a redirection URL and a message to display on my web site.  My app periodically checks the site for the update file, if it exists, it checks the version against it's version and if greater, it pops a dialog displaying the message from the XML file.  If they click yes, then it redirects them using a browser intent to the URL from the XML file (In the live app, I make that URL a market url that sends the user to the market place)

You could also possibly use the push notification for versions that support it.